# Allow OptionSelector to Scroll While Expanded

Tags: application-development, qml, javascript

My QML app uses an `OptionSelector` to allow users to choose from a list of items.  On tablet size, I have it set to keep it `expanded`.  However, I limit the container height, and while it's expanded, it cannot be scrolled.  Is there a way to let it expand without blocking scrolling?

Code:

```
OptionSelector {
    id: projectSelector
    property int projectIndex: 0
    width: pageLayout.width
    model: projects.count > 0 ? projects : emptyList

    containerHeight: pageLayout.height - itemHeight - units.gu(3)
    expanded: true
}
```

Comment: Could you please attach the relevant part of your code to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `OptionSelector.currentlyExpanded` instead of `OptionSelector.expanded` makes it expanded initially, but as soon as you select an option, it collapses.  This is closer to what I want, but not the most optimal solution.

```
OptionSelector {
    id: projectSelector
    property int projectIndex: 0
    width: pageLayout.width
    model: projects.count > 0 ? projects : emptyList

    containerHeight: pageLayout.height - itemHeight - units.gu(3)
    currentlyExpanded: true
}
```